rails form_with save file path to database for active storage to import images
I'm wanting to have the user select a data file and select a directory (different than the data file location) for images to be imported using active_storage as a background_job in Ruby on Rails.
What type of field can I use in form_with that will allow the file path to be saved for active storage to use after the data file has been imported?
I tried a file_field :photos_path to select a directory in the form
Then in the controller get the path in the params
    if params[:report][:photos_path].present?
      @report.photos_path = params[:report][:photos_path].path
      p @report.photos_path
    end

but that returns the active storage tmp path
11:27:18 web.1  | "/var/folders/bm/6t88t37133d2b6_j1npz5qn80000gn/T/RackMultipart20241121-84847-g5ihzm.csv"

The actual goal is to provide a unique folder directory for active storage to use to import images after the data file has already been imported.
record.photo.attach(io: File.open(Rails.public_path.join("#{file_path}/#{image_name}")), filename: "#{image_name}.jpg", content_type: "image/jpeg", identify: false)


You are attempting to allow the user to select a directory in your active_storage provider's directory structure?

I would like the user to select a directory on our network in a form and provide that directory to active_storage to import images from at a later time. I'm merging 2 data files together to create one report and wanting to import images from the user provided file path. I have the data merge working and images import from a static file path so I'm close to a final solution.

So you are assuming that everything in the folder should be used and the app will have access to everything and nothing will change in the folder between the user’s request and the time you perform the import—hmmmm

@report.photos_path.local_path same result as params[:report][:photos_path].path

This really just violates the whole philosophy of ActiveStorage which is that only the service really cares about how the file is stored. You're going to be fighting it tooth and nail for very little gain. Either don't use AS or rethink if you actually want to implement whatever feature you're actually trying to build this way.

A better way is to think of the problem is in terms of models. If uploads need to be grouped together they should belong to a model that groups them.
